# how to make any app debuggable

Tags: usb-debugging, debug, developer-options

I am working on some project where I need to debug existing apps on android android market. I know by modifying androidmanifest.xml we can do so but for that I need to have source code. So is there any short way to to this task. Can "select debug app" option in developer options help ?

Comment: You may be interested in researching `apktool`.

Comment: Is your device rooted and has the Xposed framework installed? If so, e.g. [XInstaller](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.xinstaller) can do that.

Comment: @Izzy No.  Device is not rooted

Comment: In that case, you probably will have to go the "recompile" way our Salesman managed ([here's a howto for that](https://gist.github.com/nstarke/615ca3603fdded8aee47fab6f4917826), so maybe you can "semi-automate" it).